# How should I allocate space for a list of items when I don't know in advance how many I'm going to have?

Tags: delphi

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6257649/744588), [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan) posted a comment about his "all time least favourite Delphi construct":

```
SetLength(FItems, Length(FItems)+1);
```

The construct he dislikes was heavily used in the [Pebongo](http://code.google.com/p/pebongo/) project, such as in [this excerpt](http://code.google.com/p/pebongo/source/browse/trunk/_bson.pas?r=9#481):

```
procedure TBSONDocument.ReadStream( F: TStream ); 
var 
  len : integer; 
  elmtype : byte; 
  elmname : string; 
begin 
  Clear; 
  f.Read( len, sizeof( len ) ); 
  f.Read( elmtype, sizeof( byte ) ); 

  while elmtype <> BSON_EOF do // Loop
  begin 
    elmname := _ReadString( f ); 
    SetLength( FItems, length( FItems ) + 1 ); // This, spotted by TOndrej
    case elmtype of 
      BSON_ARRAY: FItems[high( FItems )] := TBSONArrayItem.Create; 
      BSON_BINARY: FItems[high( FItems )] := TBSONBinaryItem.Create; 
      ...
    end; 
    f.Read( elmtype, sizeof( byte ) ); 
  end; 
end;
```

What are the alternatives?

Comment: Supposedly, length should be stored somewhere else to avoid extra calls to Length. OR you can write `len = Length(FItems); SetLength(Result.FItems, len); for i := 0 to len - 1 do` etc.

Comment: I don't think your code here applies to that. David meant that you should not increase the length of FItems one item at a time in a loop. This code sets the length one time and then loops so it should be good.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson: The snippet code is not mine, it's from the [Pebongo](http://code.google.com/p/pebongo/) project on which David has made a good guess.

Comment: You're right, @Mikael. I've edited the question to include an accurate example of the problematic code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I was talking about was growing dynamic arrays 1 element at a time:

```
SetLength(FItems, Length(FItems)+1);
```

In a loop, and with large arrays, this can lead to memory address fragmentation. When this happens you can find yourself unable to allocate a large contiguous block of memory even though the total available address space is large. If you are constrained by 32 bit address space this can be a very real problem. In addition, performance can also be an issue.

There are a variety of ways to avoid the problem:

- Pre-allocate the array. Sometimes this involves iterating twice, once to count the items and once to populate the array. This can be perfectly efficient. In fact, that is precisely what `TBSONDocument.Clone` in your question does.
- Use a `TList` or `TList<T>` container. Although these use dynamic arrays as their underlying storage they implement a capacity based approach to allocation. When they are full, they allocate a large number of extra items in anticipation for future additions. This again can be perfectly efficient.
- Yet another option, to be used as a last resort, is to move away from contiguously allocated memory. Allocate memory in chunks and use an indexed property of a class or record to map between indices and the actual chunk and location where the storage lives. This is particularly effective at avoiding address space fragmentation.

Comment: Array pre-allocation is obvious, I delved into TList source code and noticed that the second technique is the prefered one used by many JSON parser writers. Up till now, I never succeeded to find sample code illustrating the (last resort) third option. Does it imply the use a custom Manager to delegate chunk handling tasks? Maybe that deserves another post.

Answer (score 9):

It's not the `SetLength()` itself that is bad but incrementing the length in the loop. Example of bad code:

```
SetLength( Result.FItems, 0 ); 

for i := 0 to high( FItems ) do 
begin 
  SetLength(Result.FItems, Length(Result.Fitems)+1);
  Result.FItems[i] := FItems[i].Clone; 
end;
```

In this case array is rearranged and reallocating memory on each iteration. Your posted example doesn't show bad usage of `SetLength()`

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't incur any penalty ?

Comment: In my example it is very inefficient. It is much better to use TList in such cases.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative would be to use a list like `TList`, `TObjectList`, or a generic list.

Actually, the part you posted (`SetLength(Result.FItems, Length(FItems));`) is fine. I believe David was referring to another part: `SetLength(FItems, Length(FItems) + 1);` which is supposed to grow a dynamic array and can be inefficient in a loop.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative you can use when the number of items is unknown beforehand: Increase the length of the array every X items, and at the end adjust the length of the array to the number of items added.

Example:

```
Count := 0;
try
  while not Query.EOF do
  begin
    if Length(MyArray) = Count then
      SetLength(MyArray, Length(MyArray) + 50); //increase length with 50 items
    MyArray[Count] := Query.Fields(0).AsString;
    Inc(Count);
    Query.Next;
  end;
finally
  SetLength(MyArray, Count); //adjust length to number of items added
end;
```

Comment: Accessing a dataset may cause exceptions to be thrown, therefore it's really important to use a `finally` to force the last line to always be executed - otherwise `MyArray` may contain empty strings at the end that weren't read from the query.

Answer (score 0):

A TList utilizes the non-contiguous memory style that David refers to. This is an addon to his answer.

Here's a real world analogy:

**"Cars in a parking lot": An analogy for List of Objects versus an Array of Records**

**The Array**

You have a row of cars in the parking lot filled up. The row of cars is an array. The actual cars are stored in the array. The size of the array in memory is the size of all of the real cars combined.

**Adding a car to an Array**

Let's say you want to add another car, but there's no more room in the row. So, you have to build a new row that's bigger and move all the cars over into the new row. You have to do this each time you want to add one to the row. That's an array.

**The List**

What if you put the cars in a list by writing their VINs onto a piece of paper? Each VIN refers to a car out in the parking lot. That list on the paper is a TList. It just stores a reference to each of the cars.

**Adding a car to a TList**

Now, let's say you want to add a car to the list. Well, you can park the car anywhere. If your lot's full, park it in Alaska. It doesn't matter. Just add the new VIN to the list, and you're done. If your paper fills up, get another piece of paper. But, don't move the cars.

> TList is good because the actual list items aren't stored in the list.
>   It's just pointers to the items. Those pointers are relatively small,
>   plus TList pre-allocates space (in the analogy, each sheet of paper).

Comment: On the other hand, `TList<T>` uses contiguous blocks. Old style `TList` is the ultimate limit of the approach described in my 3rd bullet point.

Comment: Your analogy is nice, but you ignore one crucial thing: A `TList` uses an array of pointers to the items contained, so if we are talking about strings, object references or such (everything that is not larger than the size of a pointer) then with Delphi there is hardly any difference between `TList` and Array. In these (common) cases `TList` does most certainly **not** utilize "the non-contiguous memory style that David refers to" any more than an array does. It implements some nice methods to modify the contained array, and `Capacity` allows some optimization (as in other answers).

Comment: [I assume that your `TCar` would be an object or interface pointer, not a record.]

Comment: mghie, there are exceptions, but analogies are best kept short. My analogy is Arrays of Records vs. List of Object Pointers. Thanks for the info.